# If subsequence of strictly monotone sequence is bounded then sequence bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In **Example 3.7.6 (c)**  textbook "Introduction to Real analysis by Bartle 4th edition" authors gives a short proof of the convergence of series $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Solution goes like this "since the partial sum are monotone, it suffices (**why?**) to show that, some subsequence of sequence of partial sum $(s_k)$ is bounded.......

**My question is** why it suffices?

According to me, if we show some **subsequence** of $(s_n)$ is bounded  then this implies $(s_n)$ is bounded (because $(s_n)$ is strictly monotone)  and then we can use **theorem 3.7.5** (which states that, if $(x_n)$ is sequence of non-negative real numbers then $\sum x_n$ converges iff sequence of partial sum is bounded" ) to show given series $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

**Am i correct**?

**Further**, why authors just used the world monotone? I think we must need strictly monotone! Because for example: sequence $(1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,....)$ is monotone increasing. It has bounded subsequence $(0,0,0,...)$ **But, it not bounded**.

Please help....

Comment: $(1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,...)$ is not monotone increasing; $(1,1,1,1,1,...)$ is monotone increasing and $(1,2,3,4,5,...)$ is strictly monotone increasing

Comment: @J.W.Tanner oops :-) Than you sir. What about first part of question?

Comment: Please tell me? Is an i correct about first part or question? That is, "why it suffices" part?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Yes, you are right about the first part.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you so... much sir for confirmation.